# Finding out the magnetic field inside the cross section of the torus which is wrapped by conductive wire and the current flows it

Tags: electromagnetism, coil, solenoid, homework, math

[image]

As shown in the diagram , the torus of radius of \$~ R ~\$  exists .

The wire is wrapped around the torus .

$$  N:=\text{total number of the turns of the wire around the torus }  $$

The current is flown inside the wire .

$$  I:=\text{current }  $$

$$  r:=\text{radius of cross section of the torus }  $$

$$  H:=\text{magnetic field at } ~ \left( r,\theta_{}  \right)   $$

Currently I have the dought  of the below equation . I've been unable to derive the below rightmost formula .

$$  NI = \int_{ }^{ } \boldsymbol{H}\cdot\boldsymbol{ds}  = H\cdot  2\pi \left( R+r \cos^{}\left(\theta_{} \right)  \right)    $$

I confidentially guess that the above equation is gained by the law of Ampere .

We assume the circle of radius \$~ \left( R+ r \cos^{}\left(\theta_{} \right)  \right)  ~\$ which circumference is inside the flesh of the torus .

We assume the closed path . The path is made by the circumference of the circle which we defined previously .

\$~ NI ~\$ makes sense of penetrations of each current(\$~ I ~\$ ) to the closed surface .

I assume \$~ ds= \left( R+ r \cos^{}\left(\theta_{} \right)  \right) d\theta  ~\$

$$  NI = \int_{ }^{ } \boldsymbol{H}\cdot\boldsymbol{ds}  = H\cdot  2\pi \left( R+r \cos^{}\left(\theta_{} \right)  \right)    $$

$$ = \int_{0 }^{2\pi  } H \cdot \left\{ \left( R+ r \cos^{}\left(\theta_{} \right)  \right)d\theta   \right\}    $$

$$ = \int_{0 }^{2\pi  } H \cdot  \left( R+ r \cos^{}\left(\theta_{} \right)  \right)d\theta      $$

I've been stucked from here since \$~ H ~\$ includes the information of \$~ \theta_{}  ~\$ and, the form  of formula of \$~ H ~\$  is unknown so far .

What I should focus for next?

Comment: \$\alpha\$ is the internal cross sectional radius of the toroid not \$r\$. Dimension \$r\$ is the distance of point \$P\$ from the centre of the toroid's cross section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I assume $$ds= \left( R+ r \cos^{}\left(\theta_{} \right)  \right) d\theta$$

No. ds refers to a small displacement *around* the torus, (i.e. around the torus's axis of symmetry. ) By symmetry, B or H is the same at all points in a circle around the axis of symmetry, so for such a path, B or H is constant and can be taken outside of the integral. This modified integral is then just the circumference of that circle.

$$\oint ds= 2\pi  \left( R+ r \cos^{}\left(\theta_{} \right)  \right)$$

Comment: About "around the torus's axis of symmetry" , needless to say that this "around" includes inside the flesh of the torus?

Comment: Using your 

$$\oint ds= 2\pi  \left( R+ r \cos^{}\left(\theta_{} \right)  \right)$$

, I wrote the below equations. 

$$  NI = \int_{ }^{ } \boldsymbol{H}\cdot\boldsymbol{ds}  = H  \oint ds =  H \cdot   \left\{  2\pi  \left( R+ r \cos^{}\left(\theta_{} \right)  \right) \right\}    $$

Comment: "needless to say that this "around" includes inside the flesh of the torus? " Yes, the  B or H is constant along any circle centered around the axis of symmetry of the torus, whether inside the "flesh" or outside (where it is 0).

Comment: It is quite weird for me that H can be taken out from the integrator .

Comment: Since H includes the information of \$\theta ~~,~~ r \$

Comment: I have to recap what I want to say .

Comment: "I wrote the below equations." Yes, but you said you were unable to derive it.  "It is quite weird for me that H can be taken out from the integrator ." H is not constant with respect to theta, but it _is_ constant with respect to s as s traverses a circle centered around the axis of symmetry. That is why you can move H outside the integral.

Comment: $$ds= \left( R+ r \cos^{}\left(\theta_{} \right)  \right) d\theta ~~ \leftarrow~~ \text{wrong form}  $$
 
$$  ds= \left( R+ r \cos^{}\left(\theta_{} \right)  \right) d\phi ~~ \leftarrow~~ \text{correct form}   $$

$$  \phi_{} ~~\text{can be seen as we see the torus from upside }  $$ 

$$  \therefore ~~  \oint ds= \int_{0 }^{2\pi  } \underbrace{ \left( R+ r \cos^{}\left(\theta_{} \right)  \right)}_{\text{constant} }  d\phi   $$ 

$$ = \left( R+ r \cos^{}\left(\theta_{} \right)  \right) \int_{0 }^{2\pi  } d\phi    $$

$$ = 2\pi \left( R+ r \cos^{}\left(\theta_{} \right)  \right) $$

Comment: My conclusion .